# There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: c. in DropDownMultiSelect() widget

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-listview

I have `DropDownMultiSelect()` element in my form and I add `5 DropDownMultiSelect()` elements in my form but there is an error showing in the console and i.e
`There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: c.  Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value`

Can anyone please tell me how can I resolve this error?

Here is my code:-

```
class _Editprofile extends State<Editprofile>{

    List<String> selected = [];
    List<String> selected1 = [];
    List<String> selected2 = [];
    List<String> selected3 = [];
    List<String> selected4 = [];

   @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context){

  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    titleSpacing: 3,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0,
    title: Text('Edit Profile', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15,),),
    leading: Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 0),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              width: 30,
              'assets/images/Menu.svg',
              height: 30,
            ),
            onPressed: () { Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); },
            tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      Padding(
          padding: sidePadding,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              SvgPicture.asset(
                width: 30,
                'assets/images/search.svg',
                height: 30,
              ),
            ],
          )

      )

    ],

  ),
  backgroundColor: Color(0xff8f9df2),

  body: Container(
          Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Looking for",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    addVerticalSpace(10),
                    DropDownMultiSelect(
                      onChanged: ( List<String> x ) {
                        setState(() {
                          selected = x;
                        });
                      },
                      options: ['Relationship' , 'Casual' , 'Networking' , 'Friendship', 'Unsur'],
                      selectedValues: selected,
                      whenEmpty: 'Please select',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            addVerticalSpace(20),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Politics",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    addVerticalSpace(10),
                    DropDownMultiSelect(
                      onChanged: (List<String> y) {
                        setState(() {
                          selected1 =y;
                        });
                      },
                      options: ['Conservation' , 'Liberal' , 'Apolitical' , 'Moderate'],
                      selectedValues: selected1,
                      whenEmpty: 'Please select',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
       addVerticalSpace(20),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Religion",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    addVerticalSpace(10),
                    DropDownMultiSelect(
                      onChanged: (List<String> z) {
                        setState(() {
                          selected2 =z;
                        });
                      },
                      options: ['Spiritual' , 'Roman catholic' , 'Protestant' , 'Anglican', 'Muslim', 'Hindu', 'Sikh', 'Buddhist'],
                      selectedValues: selected2,
                      whenEmpty: 'Please select',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              addVerticalSpace(20),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Children",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    addVerticalSpace(10),
                    DropDownMultiSelect(
                      onChanged: (List<String> c) {
                        setState(() {
                          selected3 = c;
                        });
                      },
                      options: ['One day' , "Have + don't want more" , 'Have and want more' , 'Do not want', 'Undecided'],
                      selectedValues: selected3,
                      whenEmpty: 'Please select',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              addVerticalSpace(20),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Interests",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    addVerticalSpace(10),
                    DropDownMultiSelect(
                      onChanged: (List<String> i) {
                        setState(() {
                          selected4 =i;
                        });
                      },
                      options: ['Art' , 'Sports' , 'Reading' , 'Politics', 'Treking', 'Cooking', 'Outdoor activites', 'Painting'],
                      selectedValues: selected4,
                      whenEmpty: 'Please select',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
    )
  }
}
```

Please, anyone, help me with how can I resolve this error
Here is the error image[image: Error in console log]

Please help me with this error I don't know what is the error because i didn't see it in my file.
please help me

Comment: Can minimize the snippet with [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what are using for `DropDownMultiSelect`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `'Please select'` in options array and if the error goes you can remove it after selection is made in the `onChanged` from the selected1,2,3,4 arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't get it